# mybatis NOT printing queries in console

Tags: eclipse, log4j, mybatis

I've follower a lot of how-tos, tutorials, guides and answers (here on SO) but still I'm unable to print queries (and their results) into Eclipse's console...

Even though I've done everything I could I'm 100% sure I'm missing something...

The mapper is in a XML class. The following is mybatis-config.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN'
  'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd'>
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
    </typeAlias>
    <mappers>
        <package name="com.app.dao.persistence" />
    </mappers>
    <typeHandlers>
        <package name="com.app.typehandler" />
    </typeHandlers>
    <settings>
    <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

And this is the log4j.properties:

```
# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout, ERROR

log4j.logger.com.app.portal=info, debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework=info
log4j.logger.com.ocpsoft=info

# MyBatis logging configuration...
log4j.logger.com.app.dao.persistence.MyMapper=TRACE
```

The XML is, obviously, in: com.app.dao.persistence.MyMapper

Comment: I have it working in my application using log4j2: <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J2"/>

Comment: How do you start your application? If you start it not from eclipse do you get the log in the console? Basically the question is if this is the problem that the log does not get to stdout of your application or that stdout of your application does not get to eclipse console. If you print something manually via `System.out.print` is it shown where you expect it to see?